# Dockerfile inheriting ENV from base image with unexpected result

Tags: docker, dockerfile, podman

I have three `Dockerfile`s with two of them providing base images to their siblings as follows:

```
# Dockerfile.a (for building image-a)
FROM debian:latest
# ...

# Dockerfile.b (for building image-b)
ARG INDEX
FROM image-a
# ...
ENV INDEX=$INDEX
# ...

# Dockerfile.c (for building image-c)
ARG INDEX
FROM image-b
# ...
ENV INDEX=$INDEX
# ...
```

Builds are done with `for ABC in a b c; do podman build -f Dockerfile.$ABC -t $image-$ABC:latest --build-arg INDEX=1 ...; done"`.

What I currently observe is that in a running instance of `image-c` `$INDEX` is empty, i.e. does not equal `1`. Am I making an obvious mistake here? Is the repeated use of `INDEX` both as `ARG` and `ENV` and across the chain of inheritance perhaps interfering with the normal semantics of `ARG INDEX ... ENV INDEX=$INDEX` in `Dockerfile.c` somehow?

Comment: Try moving ARG after FROM in each file. FROM 'resets' everything in a Dockerfile and should normally be the first line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use ARG before FROM if you need to parametrize your image. In order to use the same build argument later, your have to define the ARG again after FROM:

```
ARG INDEX
FROM image-b-${INDEX} // just example
ARG INDEX
ENV INDEX=${INDEX}
```